# Leaflet - MultiPolyline constructor and arrays in JSON

Tags: leaflet, json

I am struggling with the AntPath Plugin ( [link to GitHub](https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/leaflet-ant-path)  ) for Leaflet and the documentation is limited and difficult to read. This setup works well(se code-snippet in the end), but instead I want to add multipolylines. To do that I must change it to:L.MultiPolyline.MultiAntPath(path) and modify JSON-file to my array of polylines.

The valid and working JSON-file for current polyline looks like this:

```
[[-3.748494, -38.460304],[-3.74845, -38.4603],[-3.7482748, -38.46086]]
```

But I want something like this(Example for 2 paths):

```
[[55.778659,12.151137  ], [55.779807,12.158085  ], [55.773663,12.163626  ], [55.769615,12.16311  ]], [[55.766945,12.158487  ], [55.767806,12.154152  ], [55.769787,12.150391  ], [55.772687,12.147922  ]]
```

How does the setup look like when adding multiple polylines with lat/lon in my new JSON-file (see 2 paths-example)?

```
    $http.get('newsingle.json').then(function (res) {
                path = res.data;

                L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                }).addTo(map);

                layer = new L.Polyline.AntPath(path);
                map.addLayer(layer);
                map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
            });

            scope.$watch('options', function (opts) {
                if (layer !== null) {
                    map.removeLayer(layer);
                    layer = new L.Polyline.AntPath(path, opts);
                    map.addLayer(layer);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. This is an example of 3 paths in JSON:

[image]